# Is this PDA correct or an erratum? (Sipser example 2.14)

Tags: automata

[image]

I don’t understand this state diagram. What if $n=0$? Then our input string is the empty string. We begin at $q_1$, push \$ onto the string, move to $q_2$ but then fail. So the language recognized by this PDA is $n \geq 1$. If, however, we change the label on the vertical arrow to $\varepsilon, \varepsilon \rightarrow \varepsilon$, then we *do* recognize $n \geq 0$ as required, I think?

I checked Sipser’s online errata but didn’t see anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your given is a non deterministic PDA. It can either stop at $q_1$ or move to $q_2$ at the start. So, for empty input, it will still accept since $q_1$ is an accept state.

Comment: Thank you! My brain totally missed the double circle on $q_1$